# Creating a reference for the element while creating the element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I would like to make some kind of a map with references to objects.

The map should receive the instance of the objects as they are being rendered, however I get a:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
```

On:

```
this._boxes.set(box.props.id, ref);
```

Code:

```
  addRef = (box) => {
    let ref = React.createRef();
    this._boxes.set(box.props.id, ref);

    return ref;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="game">
        {[0, 1, 2].map(col => (
          <div key={col}>
            {[0, 1, 2].map(row => (
              <Box key={row} ref={(box) => this.addRef(box)} id={col * 3 + row} handleClick={this.props.click} />
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Do I get the error because the object is not initialized yet? Is there a better way to do it?

I know I send the id as a parameter instead, but I'd like to get the instance of the object for further use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref was reset most likely to null, check that it is not null in your addRef function:

```
addRef = (box) => {
  let ref = React.createRef();
  if (box) {
    this._boxes.set(box.props.id, ref);
  }
  return ref;
 }
```

This is expected behavior, not a mere workaround: `React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.` https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

Comment: It is null, but your solution does not solve the problem, it simply avoids the error.

Comment: This is expected behavior, React will call your callback with null untill the component mounts and after it unmounts https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs `React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.` so you need to check that it is not null